# How get shipping methods from quote

Tags: magento2

Hi i am trying to get shipping methods and cost of all methods available for that quote but before the user selection

below is my code

```
public function getShippingFromQuote()
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/mylog.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        
        
        $quoteId = 598;
        try {
            $getShippingMethods = $this->shippingMethodManagement->getList($quoteId);
            $logger->info("quoteid" . $getShippingMethods);

            $methodCodes = [];
            foreach ($getShippingMethods as $method) {
                $methodCodes[] = $method->getMethodTitle() . '=>' . $method->getAmount();
            }
            $logger->info("methods" . $method->getMethodTitle());
        } catch (StateException $stateException) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__($stateException->getMessage()));
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__($exception->getMessage()));
        }
        return $methodCodes;

    }
```

I just want to know is it possible to get all the shipping methods and rate before user select the shipping methods.

thanks

Comment: What you want to do after getting shipping methods and rates? Please explain actual requirement

Comment: if  there are more than two shipping then i will merge there price and will show a third shipping methods instead of those two methods